# Windows directory name is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

Here is my code I'm trying this but it keeps repeating the same error.
If I am doing something Wrong please tell me.

```
import os
import sys

for x in sys.argv:
    for ff in os.listdir(x):
        path = os.path.join(x, ff)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            print('\n--' + path)
        else:
            print('\t------' + path)
```

This is the error keep repeating, again and again, please someone help me out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/projects/Intern/file&folders/cc.py", line 5, in <module>
    for ff in os.listdir(x):
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'E:/projects/Intern/file&folders/cc.py'
```

Comment: What are the arguments you passing while running the script?

Comment: You  have to use backslash instead of forward slash for directories in windows. pass E:\projects\Intern\file&folders\cc.py as argument and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code:-

```
import os
import sys

for x in sys.argv[1:]:
    for ff in os.listdir(x):
        path = os.path.join(x, ff)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            print('\n--' + path)
        else:
            print('\t------' + path)
```

You were passing the whole `sys.argv` list to `os.listdir()` function. The first element is always the script itself which is not a directory. Therefore, we sliced the argument list by first element.

Answer (score 0):

I had an an similar error some years ago on a Windowsmachine. I think the Problem is that you path contains an special character (&)... Just change the name of the folder or escape it with backspace

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that some paths contain the character `&` that isn't well supported.
Try to change that folder name and avoid such characters, or try to skip paths that may contain it.